# Visual Studio Team Services build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I've got an Visual Studio Team Services account, I was an "early adopter" and have only recently started being interested in the build features.

Everywhere seems to suggest that a hosted build controller is just there when you create a new build definition.

I'm getting a TF225001 error when I try to create a new build definition. I've searched high and low to try and find a way to fix this.

I've associated my Visual Studio Team Services account with my Azure account/subscription and can confirm that it's linked.

I've specifically set my Visual Studio Team Services login to be a member of the build administrators group and anything else specific to build.

I still get the error after logging in and logging out.

Is there a delay with linking an account to Azure and being able to see the hosted build controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue on the Microsoft end.

If anyone gets a TF225001 error when trying to create a new build definition and there aren't any build controllers in the manage build controllers window. You will need to contact the visual studio online product team.

They made a change to something which allowed me to see the Build Controller and that allowed me to create a build definition.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following troubleshooting steps:

- Go to the Builds section of the Team Explorer toolbox in Visual Studio
- Click Actions -> Manage Build Controllers
- In the list you should see a controller named "Hosted Build Controller (Hosted)" and an agent named "Hosted Build Agent"
- Select the controller, click Properties and ensure the Build Controller is enabled (don't worry if it's offline - that is normal - but it should be enabled)
- Select the agent and do the same thing

Comment: This doesn't work, the hosted build controller doesn't appear.

Comment: If the "hosted build controller" doesn't appear, I think there is something wrong in your Visual Studio Online Account ... Maybe in this case the only think is contacting the Microsoft Support so that they will check your account

Comment: The hosted build controller should always appear.  You don't need to link your Visual Studio Online account with your Azure subscription to get it to start showing.

Comment: I had to go to Build > edit build > General > Default Queue > Manage to see the build controller properties.